# Как увеличить размер фрагмента карты, так же как у гугла (api staticmap)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-static-maps-api

У Гугла есть `api staticmap`, у которого есть параметр `scale=2`, меняя значение на `1` или `2` можно отлично увеличить карту:

[Государственный исторический музей в Москве](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=640x640&visual_refresh=true&scale=2&center=55.755395,37.617818&zoom=17&maptype=roadmap)

Вопрос, можно ли так же увеличить карту Яндекса api staticmap? У Яндекса тоже есть такой же параметр, но он увеличивает карту в пределах 600х450, а у Гугла получается можно бесплатно получить размер как минимум в два раза больше.

Answer (score 1):

Static API позволяет делать карты только размером до 600х450, это ограничение сервиса.
Если Вам не обязательно нужен API, постоянно получающий актуальные данные с сервера, можно получить статическое изображение карты большего размера [в Конструкторе](https://yandex.ru/map-constructor/?from=SO).

Comment: Арина, верно мне не обязательно максимально актуальные данные с сервера. 
Мне важнее всего получить ссылку на карту (по долготе и широте) в формате jpg или png (короче любом) и размером побольше, как у гугла. 
Уже второй день мучаюсь ищу ответ, но ничего найти не могу.

Comment: Ну вот в Конструкторе карт Вы сможете сохранить себе карту в этих форматах большого размера и с разрешением достаточным для полиграфической печати. Дальше выложить её на хостинг и запрашивать по ссылке - дело техники.